# Unary And Binary Minus in Parse Tree

Tags: c++, operator-precedence, unary-operator, parse-tree, binary-operators

I am creating a parse tree that will contain expressions similar to

`3 - 4 * 8`

or

`8 * -5`

or

`-(10 * 1)`

I need a way to distinguish between the unary and binary minus. The way my grammar is going now the binary minus is reached first, but I am thinking of changing that and adding a flag variable that holds the last variable.

Ex: if it is `5 - 6`

The flag is holding 5 and if it sees minus and the flag is a number the skip unary and go to binary.

However I am not sure exactly how to implement this in C++

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean a way to distinguish them as you're doing the parsing, or a way to distinguish them in the parse tree? In the parse tree, it's trivial -- just have separate `UNARY_MINUS` and `BINARY_MINUS` operators. If you mean as you're parsing, a unary minus occurs when you're expecting an operand, not an operator.

Comment: In my parser I would like it to distinguish between a -5 and 4 -5. My next part converts the leafs of this Tree to as AST tree (which is working) but my parser sees everything as a binary minus (4 - 5).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest way to implement a parser is by the method of [Recursive Descent](http://www.engr.mun.ca/~theo/Misc/exp%5fparsing.htm). Make sure to give binary minus a higher priority than unary minus, like in the referenced site:

```
 E -->  | E "+" E
        | E "-" E
        | "-" E
        | E "*" E
        | E "/" E
        | E "^" E
        | "(" E ")"
        | v
```

Comment: After looking at the site I may re write my grammar rules to follow those of the site, but one problem with that is that this parser must also be able to handle  = , < , <=, >, >=, and, or, not

Comment: @Dfranc3373 see  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence for the complete operator precedence for C++

Comment: @Dfranc3373 Great! BTW, did you already read the FAQ http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask on how to score answers? You have accepted an answer to every question that you asked, which is great, but you can also score any answer that you find useful.